# Remove a named volume with docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, volumes, docker-named-volume

If I have a docker-compose file like:

```yml
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/db
volumes:
  db-data:
```

... then doing `docker-compose up` creates a named volume for `db-data`. Is there a way to remove this volume via `docker-compose`? If it were an anonymous volume, then `docker-compose rm -v postgres` would do the trick. But as it stands, I don't know how to remove the `db-data` volume without reverting to `docker` commands. It feels like this should be possible from within the `docker-compose` CLI. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
docker-compose down -v
```

removes all volumes attached. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

Comment: You can also use `docker-compose rm -f -v`

Comment: @herm Thanks, works. Comment above mine does **not** work for **named** volumes as clearly stated in the docs. Btw., I find it extremely confusing that identically named options (`-v`) behave entirely different depending on the command (`rm` vs `down`).

Comment: Although not `docker-compose` per se, you can also remove a volume with `docker volume rm [name]` e.g `docker volume rm db-data`. See also `docker volume prune`

Comment: This only removes anonymously created volumes, not the named ones.

Comment: If you do not want to duplicate configuration data, you have to parse docker-compose.yaml and execute `docker volume rm` based on the volumes found

Comment: I believe the question is asking how to delete a specific named volume, not all of them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 72):

There's no way to target the removal of a specific named volume with the `docker compose` command. Instead this can be achieved using the `docker volume` command. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_rm/).

Use `docker volume ls` to find the name of specific volume.

Remove the volume using `docker volume rm VOLUME_NAME`. You will need to have stopped and removed containers using the volume.

An example approach:

```bash
# The "-sf" flags will stop the container and skip confirmation of the removal
docker compose rm -sf NAME_OF_SERVICE

# Next find your volume name in the following list
docker volume ls

# Finally remove the volume
docker volume rm VOLUME_NAME
```

Edit: The answer is updated to reference the `docker compose` command as the `docker-compose` cli is no longer maintained [since July 2023](https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/).

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is really the only way to remove a named volume and should be the accepted answer. Why they made it so damned hard, I don't fully understand.

Comment: The command `docker-compose rm -fv pgsql` seems to delete both the container and the attached anonymous volumes

Comment: It should read `docker compose stop <name of service>` not <name of container>, right?

Comment: Note that you can combine stopping and removing the container (see the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_rm/)): `docker compose rm -s <name of servcie>`, where `-s` is short for `--stop`: (Stop the containers, if required, before removing)

Comment: `docker compose rm -fv pgsql` does delete anonymous attached volumes as well as the container, however the original question is referring to how to delete a specific named volume.

Answer (score 43):

### Jan, 2022 Update:

This removes **all** **the** **containers**, **networks**, **volumes** and **images** defined in the **docker-compose**.

```js
docker-compose down -v --rmi all
```

**"-v"** is for **all the volumes**

**"--rmi all"** is for **all the images**

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue as you, excepting I wanted to discard the working state of my grafana container while leaving the other containers running, which are running detached (ie. sudo docker-compose up -d). Here's the procedure I've come up with:

```
sudo docker-compose ps
sudo docker-compose stop grafana
sudo docker-compose rm --force grafana
sudo docker volume rm metricsmonitoring_grafana_data
sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate -d grafana
```

I don't know (without playing further) how best to determine the name of the docker volume to remove.

This is on docker-compose version 1.18.0